# Why use 'aside' tag rather than div also work in almost every place?

Tags: html

Div tag can be used everywhere. Can anybody tell me what other aspects let aside to use?

```
aside{
}

div{
}
```

Comment: just google div vs aside and you can read about the difference

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow :) Please visit [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see [how to properly ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

`<aside>` tag is used for surroundings and div is used for general purpose

so in simple words if you want a side bar then use aside and if you want to

put something in container then use `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

`div` and `aside` are both [Block HTML elements](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp), that's why they behave in a very similar manner in the DOM.

The major difference here is semantic, `aside` is supposed to be used for... well an aside of the main content, see the [W3C aside page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_aside.asp)